# Exporting Normalized Table to Matrix format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, matrix, export

To give some background, I am modeling how different home attributes affect the prices of the homes around them.  To do this, I have a table of 4,000 home sales and the demographics of each home.  I'm generating a value as a measure of "substitutability" between each pair of homes.

My first thought in creating this was to build a 4000x4000 matrix in Excel.  However, once my calculations got a little hairy, I bumped up against memory limits pretty quickly.

So now I've put the transactions into the above mentioned table and I want to build an "interaction" table, with each row being a house pair with one column as the substitutability measure.

The table structure would look something like:

```
House1ID   House2ID    SubIndex
1          2           400
1          3           450
2          3           500
```

My problem is that the statistical software package I'm using wants the data in the following format:

```
    1      2      3
1   0     400    450
2  400     0     500
3  450    500     0
```

Is there a way to go from the table structure mentioned above to the matrix output needed?

All help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
After a little more investigation, I've realized I can at generate the normalized "table" now with a View using a Cross Join.  While this doesn't really change the question at all, I thought it interesting and figured I would point out the method I was using.

Comment: Do you have a code layer?  I would generally do it in the code layer, but I'd LOVE to see a pure query-based solution for this one.

Comment: @Sonny I do not. I could write one if needed to facilitate the transformation, but I'd rather have MySQL export directly if possible!

Comment: You should post the details as an answer to your question and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) to have the data presented in the format you need.

There are some [great examples and hints on using views here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx).

Comment: Views are essentially stored queries.  Posting a query to accomplish his requirement would be much more helpful.